# trying to send SMS message brings up "Complete action using" dialog, but messaging app isn't in the list?

Tags: android, sms, android-widget

I'm trying to send open up the messaging app to start a sms message from a widget but when I start the activity I get the "Complete action using" dialog with a long list of applications but I don't see the messaging application that I think should be the default for trying to send sms messages.

Here is my code:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context,
     AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   PendingIntent smsIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sendIntent, 0);
   sendIntent.putExtra("address", "8017777777");
   sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
   views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sms_btn1, smsIntent1);

   appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views); 
  super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

}

and my manifest has this in it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what CommonsWare said, but it didn't work, but it put me on the right track (which was using the Intent.ACTION_SENDTO.  I found what I needed here:
http://snipt.net/Martin/android-intent-usage/

This is what it ended up looking like:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
   Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
   it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
   PendingIntent smsIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, it, 0);
   views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sms_btn1, smsIntent1);
```

Comment: Sorry -- I had the wrong scheme. I keep forgetting that `SENDTO` uses `smsto`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the Messenger app has an `<intent-filter>` that does not cover your MIME type.

I am not completely certain why you have that MIME type in there. I am also unclear whether that whole `Intent` will work at all. I know this works, assuming `8017777777` is a phone number:

```
Intent sms=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("tel:8017777777"));

sms.putExtra("sms_body", msg.getText().toString());

startActivity(sms);
```

Note that you do not need the `SEND_SMS` permission in this case. You only need that if you are using `SmsManager` to send the SMS directly.

[Here is a project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SMS/Sender) that demonstrates the above `Intent` syntax, plus using `SmsManager` directly, as options for how to send a text message to a contact in your contacts list.

Comment: I tried that and nothing happened at all after clicking on the button. I wonder if there is some problem because it is a widget? Intent sms=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("tel:8017777777"));
       sms.putExtra("sms_body", "body");
       
       PendingIntent smsIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, sms, 0);
       views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sms_btn1, smsIntent1);